# Moving eCommerce site to new domain. Should I redirect all product pages to new location?

Tags: ecommerce, woocommerce

I'm moving an ecommerce store from a subdomain using CubeCart to the root directory using WooCommerce.  All product urls will also change.

This site has over 1000 products, all of which are indexed.  From what I can tell though every product page only has a pagerank of 1 according to Mozilla.

So question is should I even bother redirecting these pages to their new locations?  If so, any suggested methods other than one at a time?

Also any other suggestions for maintaining SEO value would be much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of procedure are you using to move those products?
Maybe you can manage custom permalinks especially for products based on CubeCart scheme. In WP WC it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

PageRank has not been made publicly available for years. So do not make decisions based upon that.

The question should be more about how many inbound (back) links the site has and how much direct traffic you receive from these links. If the answer is, the links have little value and I do not see much traffic from them, then you can likely safely ignore any traffic from them and wait till Google catches up with the change.

Be that as it may, it never hurts to redirect a site for a period to make sure you capture all opportunities. Just redirect your sub-domain to at least the home page of the parent domain. If you can work this hard, it may be that you can redirect pages to specific new pages on your site following previous and existing patterns using regular expressions.